# Bootstrap dropdown menu open after 2 click

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a nav menu, which I got from bootstrap v-4, but I have some problems, a dropdown will appear when I click 2 times, this happens after refreshing the page. I tried to delete the other dropdown menus, but the results are still the same

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light navbar-header fixed-top bt-warning p-2" id="navbar">
<div class="container">
  <a class="navbar-brand mt-1" href="#">
    <img src="" width="40" height="40" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
    <p class="t-titlepage d-inline-block mt-1">Perpustakaanku</p>
  </a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse n-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link font-weight-bold" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link font-weight-bold" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle font-weight-bold" href="#" id="navbarDropdown1" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          <i class="fas fa-user"></i> Akun
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu  dropdown-menu-right alert-warning" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown1">
          <a class="dropdown-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center" href="#">Login <i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i></a>
          <a class="dropdown-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center" href="#">Register <i class="fas fa-file-alt"></i></a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using bootstrap CDN?

Comment: no, I use local bootstrap

Comment: By removing bootstrap.min.js, the dropdown double click issue should resolved.

Comment: oh sorry, it turns out that it happened as a result of me entering bootstrap-bundle.min.js, I deleted the bootstrap-bundle and there was no double click